# Active Learning suggestions in QnAMaker

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am using QnAMaker in my Chatbot. As per the documents I have upgraded my QnAService by restarting it and enabled the Active Learning in QnAMaker portal. Now, to test it, I used the same chit-chat knowledge which comes as an option while creating a knowledge base and started asking some questions.

[image]

The questions were closely related (but not exactly same) to existing set of questions in the knowledge base. After a while I checked the QnAMaker portal to see if there are any suggested questions. I filtered by suggested questions but don't see any new questions.

I followed the steps mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#turn-on-active-learning.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#add-active-learning-suggestion-to-knowledge-base

Below is the code snippet which I am using to query the knowledge base:

```
var qnaMakerService = _botServices.qnaMakerServices["QnAMaker"];

var qnaResult = await qnaMakerService.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (qnaResult != null && qnaResult.Length > 0)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(qnaResult[0].Answer).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
else
{
    var msg = @"I’m sorry. I could not find an answer to your question.";
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Is there something more I have to do?

Comment: Isn't adaptive learning just in the portal, so you'd need to train and publish for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Train and publish only when you can see the new question suggestions getting added to the portal through Active Learning. The problem is I don't get the suggestions added to the knowledge base as it is mentioned in the links mentioned in the details above.

Comment: Just linking here for the community to the conversation you opened up in the Azure docs repo regarding the issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25638

Comment: Commented on thread above regarding when suggestions actually appear in the portal at qnamaker.ai